# Donot know the name of this React-native component

Tags: react-native

Please can anyone guide me about this screen slider and the name of this component in React Native. Also,Please share some preferble code to create a slider like this for a screen.

here is an example Screen
[image]

Comment: react-native-bottomsheet should suit your needs

Comment: adding on to what Poptocrack has said, https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet

Comment: Thanks its very useful